# activemq 5.9 org.apache.activemq.command package missing

Tags: java, activemq-classic, slf4j

Originally my project had the `activemq-all-5.9.0.jar` but due to it including an `slf4j` binding as a dependency I am trying to use the individual jars instead and not include the `slf4j` binding.

I used the dependency list to determine the required jars
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.9.0/activemq-all-5.9.0.pom

Included jars thus far (abbreviated)

```
amqp,
broker,
camel,
client,
console,
http,
jaas,
kahadb-store,
leveldb-store,
mqtt,
openwire-legacy,
protobuf,
spring,
stomp,
j233-management,
jms,
jta
```

However, the `org.apache.activemq.command` package is still missing but it is present in the `activemq-all`.

Which jar am I missing, or which jar is command supposed to be in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it in my project in ActiveMQ Client, `activemq-client-5.9.0.jar`
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-client/5.9.0

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```